# Maven <name> tag under <project>

Tags: maven, tags, artifact

I wonder what the `<name>` tag under `<project>` does in Maven.
[Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) describes:

> name: This element indicates the display name used for the project. This is often used in Maven's generated documentation.

I usually find `<name>` tag defined in every single `pom.xml` in the project I work.
And I find it distracting, since I normally care about `<artifactid>` but not about `<name>` and both mostly have always the same string.

I guess I can simply remove them.
But just wondering about its usefulness.

Comment: The name is displayed on the console during build ...

Comment: Well, there are already many messages displayed on the console that let me identify which artifactId is being built: `Reactor Build Order` message lists artifacts, `Building <artifactId> <version>` message for each one, `@ <artifactId>` messages, `Reactor Summary`... 
It seems enough for me, and I do not see the reason for having a `<name>` tag. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `<name>..</name>` is not defined the artifactId will be shown there but you can of course overwrite that and show more descriptive text if you like. For example if you build [Apache Maven](https://github.com/apache/maven/) you see different output like the following:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Apache Maven 3.7.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Maven ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.192 s]
[INFO] Maven Model ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.047 s]
[INFO] Maven Artifact ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.030 s]
[INFO] Maven Plugin API ................................... SUCCESS [  0.017 s]
[INFO] Maven Builder Support .............................. SUCCESS [  0.012 s]
[INFO] Maven Model Builder ................................ SUCCESS [  0.054 s]
[INFO] Maven Settings ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.012 s]
[INFO] Maven Settings Builder ............................. SUCCESS [  0.023 s]
[INFO] Maven Repository Metadata Model .................... SUCCESS [  0.010 s]
[INFO] Maven Artifact Resolver Provider ................... SUCCESS [  0.021 s]
[INFO] Maven Core ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.150 s]
[INFO] Maven SLF4J Wrapper ................................ SUCCESS [  0.007 s]
[INFO] Maven SLF4J Simple Provider ........................ SUCCESS [  0.024 s]
[INFO] Maven Embedder ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.021 s]
[INFO] Maven Compat ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.125 s]
[INFO] Apache Maven Distribution .......................... SUCCESS [  0.094 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.135 s
```

For example the last line would be `apache-maven` instead of `Apache Maven Distribution` if no `<name>..</name>` would have been defined.